# On transferability of solutions to linear programs

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am interested in a sequence of linear programs of the following type, over $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$:
$$
\min c_n^T x\\
x\geq 0\\
Ax = b
$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, $n\geq 1$ and some choice of $A, b$ that remain fixed. The vector $c_n$ is given by
$$ c_n = c_1\circ c_1\circ\cdots\circ c_1 \hspace{1cm}(n\text{ times})$$
where $\circ$ is entrywise multiplication. That is, $c_n = (c_1)^{n}$ is the $n$-th **pointwise** power of some vector $c_1$. The vector $c_1$ is nonnegative off the bat.

**My question is:** Under what conditions on $c_1$ (or $A$, $b$) does it happen that a solution $x_n$ to the $n$-th such problem is also a solution to the $(n+1)$-st such problem? It would also be helpful if someone can point me to the proper terminology that might help me identify this in the literature on linear programs, so I can read more about it there. I'm not sure if this is something that has been studied extensively or not.

Comment: It seems unlikely there is any good general condition other than all entries in $c$ are equal. For $k=2$ and $c_1\neq c_2$ you have lines of increasing slope so the optimal point will be "rolling" over your feasible polytope. Since the feasible set does not change you could use primal simplex and hot-start the $n$-th solve with the solution of the $(n-1)$-st solve, that should be quite efficient, especially for those iterations where the solution stays the same.

Comment: On a side note there is only a fairly small range of $n$ where the $c_1^n$ will have reasonable numerical values that keep the problem sensible numerically, so remember scaling.